# Azure Cache locks up?

Tags: c#, caching, azure

I'm trying to get a basic cache implemented but it is locking up on the create step...

I have tried several methods of "creating the cache" but they all freeze on the same step (where I new up the DataCache object).

My solution has 1 web role and one caching worker role (created via the template) so nothing too fancy there.

my current failing code is

```
DataCache cache = new DataCache("default")
```

And the web.config in my webrole is straight out of what the nuget package installs

```
  <dataCacheClients><dataCacheClient name="default">
     <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="DataTesting.Azure.CachingRole" />
     <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
  </dataCacheClient></dataCacheClients>
```

I am not seeing anything useful in VS output, the compute emulator's consoles or anywhere else... Also the caching configurations are being saved to storage so the caching is initializing.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your code & configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, the problem may be in dot separated identifier string.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the `Exception` details (that probably being thrown eventually), i guess your `identifier` value could be wrong.

Make sure your `identifier` value is exactly as appears in Visual Studio (`eCom.Cache` in the image):

[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I entered.. I checked it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I could not get dot notation to work in this field.. I switched my caching role name to "CacheWorker" and everything works (sort of)

Comment: so dot separated identifier string is the problem. Am i right @Josh Handel?

Comment: as far as I could reproduce... yes